# Unable to compute intersection between two polygons using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, intersection, qgis-2

I have two polygons in different layers. I am trying to find the intersect between the two polygons. Below a figure showing my test case. I initially wanted to find the intersect between the green polygon and a bunch of other polygons and wrote a code for that. For all but one polygon this functioned as expected, shown below is the one polygon for which my function fails.
[image: The two polygons for which I'm trying to find the intersect]

My code:

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

layer1=None
layer2=None
for lyr in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    if lyr.name() =='Poly':
        layer1 = lyr
    if lyr.name() =='Buffer':
        layer2 = lyr

features1 = layer1.getFeatures()
features2 = layer2.getFeatures()

for feature1 in features1:
    for feature2 in features2:
        geominter=feature1.geometry().intersection(feature2.geometry())

print(geominter.area())
print(geominter.asPolygon())

layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon', 'Intersect' , 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()
layer.startEditing()
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(geominter)
prov.addFeatures([feat])
layer.commitChanges()
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

This code worked for all other polygons I needed to find the intersect for except this one. The output layer contains one element (as expected) but nothing is plotted. The print outputs of this code are:

```
30.2517066088
[]
```

It accurately computes the area of the polygon I expect to obtain but the .asPolygon() output is empty, which I expect is why nothing is plotted. What could be the reason for this, and how can I obtain the intersect between these two polygons?

I am using QGIS version 2.18.11 on Windows 8.

Comment: Hi and welcome, did you check if your troublesome polygon is valid ? If not it may be the problem. Then you should try to make it valid with a buffer for exemple.

Comment: Try changing you output layer type of MULTIPOLYGON rather than polygon.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to check if my polygon was valid or not. However adding a small (but non-zero) buffer did solve the problem. @Maximilienjaffrès Thank you very much

Comment: it was probably a non valid geometry problem, the buffer solved it. if you want to test the validity look for the Qgis tool : Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity or use python method geom.isGeosValid()

Comment: Using the python method tells me that, unexpectedly, the polygon was valid. Despite this, buffering did solve the issue.